# Listing all ArcGIS Coordinate Systems using ArcObjects?

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-10.1, arcobjects

We currently have an ArcMap addin that will convert selected or all point features to a SEGP1 file. We also allow projections to a different Coordinate System and this is where it gets tedious. We want to list out all valid coordinate system from arcgis. Currently, we have an xml file where we store the Coordinate System list.

Is there any way where we can retrieve the list of coordinate systems using ArcObjects?

We are using ArcObjects 10.1 .NET btw.

Answer (score 2):

There are hundreds of coordinate systems and that's just the projected ones...
Search the help for the enumerates *esriSRProjCSType*, *esriSRProjCS2Type*, *esriSRProjCS3Type*, or *esriSRProjCS4Type*. These would list the available projected coordinates systems, then there all the geographic ones...

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13783295/getting-all-names-in-an-enum-as-a-string) may help you step through the enumerates.